# Can a TRIM capable SSD be used on a non-TRIM system and transferred to a TRIM capable machine for maintenance?

Tags: ssd, sata, maintenance, trim

My current system has a slow hard drive, through a PATA interface. SATA interface is not an option. I am planning to replace the HDD with an mSATA SSD through a PATA adapter, though this will not allow TRIM to be used in this machine, because PATA cannot support these commands.

I am not trying to get full SATA transfer rates, only to eliminate the delay of a slow mechanical drive.

My question, is that since TRIM will be disabled in this machine, can I periodically remove the SSD and move it to another machine with a SATA controller, to run cleanup operations to free up unused data blocks from there? Does anyone foresee any problems with this arrangement?

SOLVED: It appears PATA drives suporting TRIM do exist, and [ATA-7 PATA controllers may be able to use TRIM to manage SSDs, with a suitable bridge.](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hardware-components-aftermarket-upgrades/444528-can-pata-ssds-support-trim-win7.html). Credit to Groo for suggesting this.

Comment: Realted: [Explain TRIM, and are all SSD's going to support this with firmware updates?](http://superuser.com/questions/65415/explain-trim-and-are-all-ssds-going-to-support-this-with-firmware-updates)

Comment: AFIAK TRIM happens when a file is deleted. Not a process that runs later.

Comment: My theory is that due to to lack of TRIM when files are erased, the drive can't be fully aware of blocks being freed up. I would then run fstrim ([some discussion](http://www.linux-archive.org/gentoo-user/586455-ssds-ext4-fstrim-discard.html)) from the other system, but would those blocks (that the SSD should now be aware of) be writable on the first system?

Comment: Note that TRIM is an ATA command, not specifically SATA, so you might want to check simply if your adapter forwards these commands or suppresses them.

Comment: I believe it's an ATA7 command, so the ATA4 PATA bus can't support it. EDIT - got my specs mixed up, the PATA bus may be ATA 7. I will look into it.

Comment: Most current controllers have decent garbage collection routines in the event that the host system can't use TRIM.